# Get currency symbol angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I'm building an application using angular 2 and currency pipe, but I can't find a way to get the currency symbol according to the ISO value without any number. What I mean is that I just want the symbol without setting a number to be formatted.

Normal situation `$3.00`
I want only the `$symbol`, not the number

Comment: Did you try something like `{{'' | currency:'USD':true}}` ?

Comment: You have a number with the currency symbol inside and what to get the symbol only?

Comment: In the dev branch there is a  [getLocaleCurrencySymbol](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/i18n/locale_data_api.ts#L377)

Comment: {{'' | currency:'USD':true}} will not work as '' is a string. you can try a number and it should work {{90 | currency:'USD':true}}

Comment: @trichetriche that doesn't work as the pipe is expecting a number

Comment: @Vega only the symbol

Comment: @CornelC i'll have a look on that

Comment: @AniruddhaDas yeap, but I only want the symbol as I'm not able to use a number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Angular provides an inbuilt method `getCurrencySymbol` which gives you currency symbol. You can write a pipe as a wrapper over that method as

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'currencySymbol'
})
export class CurrencySymbolPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(
    code: string,
    format: 'wide' | 'narrow' = 'narrow',
    locale?: string
  ): any {
    return getCurrencySymbol(code, format, locale);
  }
}
```

and then use as:

```
{{'USD'| currencySymbol}} ===> $
{{'INR'| currencySymbol}} ===> ₹
```

Live Stackblitz Demo:

App Url: https://angular-currency-symbol-pipe.stackblitz.io

Editor Url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-symbol-pipe

Comment: I think that today (2020), to use getCurrencySymbol() is what I would do, so I'm going to change your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Answered in 2017**:
As I ONLY wanted the symbol for the currency, I ended up extending currency pipe with a constant number and return only the symbol. It feels sort of a "hack" to have a constant number, but as i don't want to create new currency maps and I'm not able to provide a number, i think is the easiest way.

Here is what I did:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({name: 'currencySymbol'})
export class CurrencySymbolPipe extends CurrencyPipe implements 
PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): any {
    let currencyValue = super.transform(0, value,true, "1.0-2");
    return currencyValue.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    }
}
```

Now I can use it as:

```
{{ 'EUR' | currencySymbol }} and get '€'
```

Thanks for your help and ideas!

**Update**: 
Changed accepted answer to Varun's one as in 2020 I would use getCurrencySymbol() to accomplish that task

Comment: Your pipe's name is 'currencySymbol', so you should have used it like {{'EUR' | currencySymbol}} ?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is quite old but just if someone happens upon it as I have, Angular has a method to do this without having to do weird and wonderful Regex and string manipulation.

I made the following pipe using the `getCurrencySymbol` method in `@angular/common`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'currencySymbol'
})
export class CurrencySymbolPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(currencyCode: string, format: 'wide' | 'narrow' = 'narrow', locale?: string): any {
    return getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode, format, locale);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code in the template which avoids having to define a new pipe:

`{{ ( 0 | currency : currencyCode : 'symbol-narrow' ) | slice:0:1 }}`

Where `this.currencyCode` is set to the three digit currency symbol expected to be shown.

Comment: That was exactly my thought, just not sure how to write this correctly.. this should be the top answer!

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'removeAFromString'})
export class RemoveAFromString implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number){
    return value.substring(1);

  }
}
```

Now concat the pipes:

```
{{ portfolio.currentValue | currency : 'AUD' : true : '4.0' | removeAFromString}}
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't have a number to use this pipe with the normal implementation. I would like something like currency.getCurrencySymbol('EUR')

Comment: This is a very bad idea: not all currency symbols are displayed to the left of the number, AND not all currency symbols are a symbol. Try the Currency Formatter at https://marcoscaceres.github.io/jsi18n/#localize_currency to see what I mean.