# Angular 5 - currencyPipe

Tags: angular, pipe, currency, currency-pipe

I have a problem with the already built in CurrencyPipe from Angular.

I need to display a currency sign using the CurrencyPipe but I can't use it unless I provide an input number.

Because the CurrencyPipe uses the current locale to get the currency sign, I was thinking that the input number could be optional.

Current Behaviour:

```
{{ 1 | currency:'USD' }} --> $1
```

Needed Behaviour:

```
{{ null | currency:'USD' }} --> $
```

Does any of you know if this is possible with the default Pipe?
Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you do: `input ? {{input | currency:'USD':true}} : $` ? Or does it have to be strictly pipe?

Comment: That would work if the currency was only Dollars, but there are more, €, ... That was just a use case

Comment: Then it's not possible with default built-in pipe. The default CurrencyPipe returns null if the value is null. You'd need to have a custom pipe

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093388/1009922).

Comment: https://angular.dev/api/common/getCurrencySymbol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update Angular 8

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({ name: 'CustomeCurrency' })
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) { }
    transform(value: any, currencyCode?: string, display?: string | boolean, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string {
        if (value != null)
            return this.currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, display, digitsInfo, locale);
        return this.currencyPipe.transform(0, currencyCode, display, locale).split('0.00')[0];
    }
}
```

---

Try this simple custom currency pipe

`{{ null  | CustomeCurrency  }}</p>`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({ name: 'CustomeCurrency' })
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) { }

transform(value: any, currency: string, symbol: boolean = false): string {
     if (value != null)
        return this.currencyPipe.transform(value, currency, symbol);
    return this.currencyPipe.transform(0, currency, symbol).split('0.00')[0];
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did something similar to that, passing a 0 and getting a substring from the first digit till the end.

Answer (score 7):

If you're getting the error message **The currency pipe has been changed in Angular v5. The symbolDisplay option (third parameter) is now a string instead of a boolean. The accepted values are "code", "symbol" or "symbol-narrow".** then refer to the Angular documentation for help, use the code samples on this page to fix the issue: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Answer (score 7):

Use the Angular [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#usage-notes).

```
{{ money | currency:'USD':'symbol' }}
```

Comment: The answer looks to solve the problem. Could you be able to provide more info? Like the reference page for the same for the users to understand better?

Answer (score 6):

The currency pipe has been changed in Angular v5. The symbolDisplay option (third parameter) is now a string instead of a boolean. The accepted values are "code", "symbol" or "symbol-narrow".

Answer (score 4):

You can replace DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE with your currency symbol and add a space.

app.module.ts > providers

`providers: [ { provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, useValue: 'LKR ' } ],`

Answer (score 1):

I solved with custom pipe (with symbol as parameter) because I need control when and how symbols shown.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({ name: '$' })
export class MoneyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, symbol: string = null, decimalDelimiter: string = ",", thousandsDelimiter: string | null = "." ): any {
    if(!value) return symbol ? symbol + " -" : "";

    let roundValue = value.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~2));
    let valueToReturn = roundValue.replace('.', decimalDelimiter);

    if(thousandsDelimiter) valueToReturn = this.setThousandsSign(valueToReturn, thousandsDelimiter);
    return symbol ? symbol + " " + valueToReturn : valueToReturn;
  }

  private setThousandsSign(value: string, delimiter: string): string {
    return value.split("").reverse().map((str, index) => {
      if(index <= 3) return str;

      return (index%3)===0 ? str+delimiter : str;
    }).reverse().join("");
  }
}
```

That was in HTML.

```
{{order.price | $}}
```

Using custom symbol.

```
{{order.price | $:'€'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
${{amount | number: '2.2'}}
```

if `amount=5` then output-->`$5.00`

if `amount=null` then output-->`$`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your template, but if all the issue is the symbol, you can use the Material class, matPrefix before the input and put whatever symbol you need.

Ex.

```
<span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
<input matInput 
       type="number"
       min="0"
       step="0.01"
       [value]="price | currency:'':'':'1.2-2'">
```