# Angular 5 decimal mask while enter input

Tags: angular, angular5, decimal, directive, masking

Am looking for the solution while enter input value 1 its become $0.01 if input value 123 its become $1.23. maybe its duplicate question but I tried many solutions but not get working in Angular 5 please help

similar like the [angularjs 1.5](http://embed.plnkr.co/jhBCDLOvi9RGaitY2w9y/preview)

Comment: You want to use a 'currency pipe' as described in this answer to a similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670949/5580153

Comment: with currencyPipe able to convert decimal but its returning if enter 1 value $1.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can perform arithmetic calculation in interpolation. So here you use combination of arithmetic expression and currency pipe.

For example : `{{input / 100 | currency}}`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ngx-mask library for it. it is available for Angular 5. 
This is github repository https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask. you can check it out