# Is there a way i can change Dollar currency to Euro's? During Angular filtering

Tags: angularjs

So when i try to filter a tag or whatever using Angular's currency filter, it  filters it using a dollar sign, and i want it to be in euro or any other currency.. 
Thanks.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('costCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.price = 100;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="costCtrl">

<h1>Price: {{ price | currency }}</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: take a look at this :https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077521/get-currency-symbol-angular-2/46093388#46093388

Comment: try this {{ price | currency: 'EUR' : true}}

Comment: I LOVE YOU GUYS! #NoHomo